# Why do some aliases work in xterm while others don't?

Tags: bash, centos, alias, xterm

I'm transitioning to a new development environment for work, and I'm new to the xterm terminal and the CentOS operating system.

I'm trying to set up aliases in my .bashrc:

```bsh
# .bashrc
alias c='clear'
alias la='ls -a'
```

But only the `c` alias works:

```
user@host:~> la
CORRECT>lua (y|n|e|a)? no
la: Command not found.
```

but `user@host:~> c` successfully clears the terminal. I tried defining several other aliases as well (directly in the interactive terminal) and only the `c='clear'` alias worked. Why might some aliases work while others don't?

Comment: Have you already tried debugging it (which, type): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109216/l-ls-la-what-are-the-differences-and-are-there-more-of-these-commands Your alias-syntax seems correct.

Comment: @steeldriver That's not zsh, it's tcsh. The zsh autocorrect prompt could be configured to look like tcsh's, but the "command not found" message couldn't. With zsh, `.bashrc` would have no effect but interactive alias definitions would work.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' ah thanks - right idea, wrong shell ;)

Comment: I only have `ls`, not `la` or `l`, according to `which`. I used the `la=ls -a` as a minimum working example, but also tried other aliases involving `cd` and other commands. `c='clear'` was the only alias that worked.

Comment: And what does `type -a la` print? (Mentioned in the answer I linked.) Or: nevermind, see the answer above and switch from tcsh – I'm too young to know this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This prompt shows that you're running [tcsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh). Your aliases in `.bashrc` have no effect because tcsh doesn't (and can't) read bash's configuration files. Your attempts to define an alias on the command line have no apparent effect because tcsh also has a command called `alias`, but its syntax is a little different from bash. `c` is working because your (t)csh configuration happens to also have the same alias.

You probably didn't intend to use tcsh. It was the best interactive shell in the 1980s, but zsh caught up and overtook it in the 1990s, and so did bash in the 2000s. Switch to `/bin/zsh` or `/bin/bash` as your login shell:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

If you can't run chsh due to administrative restrictions, see [Changing the default shell without chsh or administrator privileges](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26556/changing-the-default-shell-without-chsh-or-administrator-privileges).

If you absolutely have to use tcsh because you absolutely need login scripts that depend on it and your administrator is living in the 1990s and won't update them, you can still use a different interactive shell. Put something like

```
setenv SHELL /bin/bash
```

in your `.login` (that's the file that tcsh reads when you log in).

Comment: Thanks! 1: You're right that I was using `tcsh`. 2. I tried `chsh...` but can't, due to administrative restrictions (though I do have /bin/bash). 3. Re: the link, I changed the default shell by adding the suggested snippet to `.login`, with a few modifications. I changed `usr/local/bin/bash` to `/bin/bash` in both cases, I deleted `. ~/.profile;` and added the `--login` flag to the `bash` command. This worked! 4. FYI, I added `setenv SHELL /bin/bash` to `.login`, and it had no effect -- when I started a new terminal, I landed directly in a `tcsh` environment again.

Comment: @JacobStern Changing `.login` doesn't change anything immediately, only when you log in. There's no reason to delete `~/.profile`.

Comment: And for sanity find out about the difference between a shell, and a terminal. And upgrade from xterm. It was OK in the 1980's.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor There's nothing wrong with xterm. Other terminal emulators don't do much that it doesn't do, and it does things that most other terminal emulators don't do (such as the ability to distinguish all key sequences, which terminals based on libvte don't have). It's maintained (two releases in 2020 so far). In contrast, tcsh doesn't do anything that zsh doesn't do, doesn't do much that bash doesn't do, doesn't do a lot that bash and zsh do. Ok, it does look like someone is maintaining it these days. But I still don't see any reason to recommend it to a new user.